# Prevent users from quitting a windows application via system hotkeys

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I've been working on a till/cash-register application. We need to prevent the users from quitting the application by using Alt + Esc, Ctrl + Alt + Del or Alt + Tab etc combinations and we'll be providing a separate custom hotkey for quiting. The application will be full-screen and without any close button. I've already done the full screen no cross button part but stuck with disabling the low system level hotkeys. How do I do this in C#? Any help or alternative methods (ie. setting up user group permissions to prevent star menu/task manager or any other alternative to achieve the goal) are appreciated.

Edit: We're using WinForms. The application will run in Windows XP/Vista/7.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @Philipp Schmid: Updated the question, sorry, I should've mentioned it earlier.

Comment: This question comes from someone who was in the trenches supporting a POS system - How will your support staff handle issues when the thing locks up and there's no way to close it other than a hard boot?  Every POS system I've seen that runs on XP/Vista/Win7 has a way to close the program using the task manager, for a reason.  If your app is completely locked up, it won't be able to respond to your hotkey.

Comment: Kiosk mode doesn't disallow ctrl-alt-del or alt-tab.

Comment: @downvoters: I don't believe you should downvote an answer because a user asks for something that's generally a bad idea. It is good to educate people and show them other paths out. A downvote in such case is not constructive.

Comment: I've asked for alternatives! I knew it was a bad move from the beginning! lol...

Comment: I didn't downvote.. I was just commenting.

Comment: If you are selling point-of-sale hardware and not an application users are expected to install on desktop machines, investigate Windows Embedded, which is designed specifically for point-of-sale systems: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-standard-7.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way to escape from the standard behavior of Windows. A user of Windows must have the possibility to kill applications. If the application doesn't obey, the system will force-kill the application.

However, there are a few tricks, often employed by virus-writers, here are some (not extensive):

- Disallowing all system hotkeys is relatively trivial, but Ctrl-Alt-Del is not amongst them. Look up [this excellent code-project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/AntonioWinLock.aspx) with a sample application.
- Build a DLL and inject yourself in other processes that are vital to the system. Easy to do, but make sure you port your application from .NET to standalone C++ or other language, you don't want system processes to be dependent on the version of .NET that *you* load.
- In lieu of the dll-suggestion, you can create something like a shell extension [with a library like this one](http://www.ssware.com/ezshell/ezshell.htm) which allows you to continue using .NET. It's not meant for this kind of thing, but it forces the user to kill `explorer.exe` to get rid of your application.
- Create a service that can interact with the desktop. Restrict the rights of the service by normal means, which essentially has the same effect of disallowing users to kill your app through the ways you mention.
- Obviously, you should cancel any `WM_CLOSE`, `WM_EXIT` or `WM_KILL` message and simply continue "living".
- Use a sentinel application, this is what most virus scanners use: if you kill one process, the sentinel will restart it. If you kill the sentinel, it should be restarted by the main app. Bad behavior, but works.

But, general advice: don't do this. Allow your users to potentially kill the program if needed, otherwise it will be very hard to do any maintenance. The only "supported" way is through services, where you can allow special users to stop your service and it cannot be stopped through task manager.

Comment: Okay so can we block everything other than Ctrl+Alt+Del from the application end? In any case, I support keeping Ctrl+Alt+Del for emergency.

Comment: @ShutterBug: it's hard to disallow alt-tab and other system keys, but you can if you want to (with a system wide hook). It's easier to kill explorer.exe and run only your app. That way alt-tab cannot do anything and task-manager is hard to come by (unless through Ctrl-Alt-Del).

Comment: @ShutterBug: also see my edit about how to disallow the system wide hotkeys through code.

Comment: @joshua: indeed, unless you take special measures as done by some (commercial) libs. But a keyboard hook has nothing to do with shell extensions, they are not related.